# How can you use smooth page scrolling with jQuery animate and update the URL at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am using a jQuery animate function with custom animation to trigger smooth page scrolling on my website. I use event.preventDefault() function call at the end of my code and with this option the page scrolls as it should but it does not update the URL. When I remove this function call, it does update the URL but beforehand the page flickers and then scrolls. I have tried without the custom animation as well but it still behaves the same. Is there a solution to this?

```
$(function () {
    $.extend($.easing,
        {
            easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
                t /= d / 2;
                if (t < 1) {
                    return c / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
                }
                t--;
                return c / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t) + 2) + b;
            }
        }
    );

    $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1600, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you got some html to match up with your javascript?

Comment: Hey Richard, thank you for your time. What do you need in particular? I don't have anything specified directly to this function in my HTML file.

Comment: Just some example html that you are using this code on. - so I can try and look and replicate it and then maybe got a solution

Comment: Just clone this repo: https://github.com/z0le12/stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hacked your html/javascript into one page.
Long story short - use a plugin
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-smooth-scrolling/blob/master/jquery.smoothscroll.js (that's what the javascript is from)

Although people say to use 'smooth-scroll'
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.asp
But I couldn't get this to work

That said this seems to be the end line

```
$scrollElement.stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': $hash.offset().top }, speed, function() {
                        location.hash = hash;
                    });
```

So basically once the animation is finished update the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Smooth scroll</title>
    <style>
        #sneaker {
  margin-top: 1500px; 
  width: 100%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-container">
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#sneaker">Take you to the sneaker</a>
      <img id="sneaker" src="adidas-superstar-2-white-black.jpg" alt="adidas superstar sneaker">
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script >
    /*! http://mths.be/smoothscroll v1.5.2 by @mathias */
;(function(document, $) {

    var $scrollElement = (function() {
        // Find out what to scroll (html or body)
            var $html = $(document.documentElement),
                $body = $(document.body),
                bodyScrollTop;
            if ($html.scrollTop()) {
                return $html;
            } else {
                bodyScrollTop = $body.scrollTop();
                // If scrolling the body doesn’t do anything
                if ($body.scrollTop(bodyScrollTop + 1).scrollTop() == bodyScrollTop) {
                    return $html;
                } else {
                    // We actually scrolled, so undo it
                    return $body.scrollTop(bodyScrollTop);
                }
            }
        }());

    $.fn.smoothScroll = function(speed) {
        speed = ~~speed || 400;
        // Look for links to anchors (on any page)
        return this.find('a[href*="#"]').click(function(event) {
            var hash = this.hash,
                $hash = $(hash); // The in-document element the link points to
            // If it’s a link to an anchor in the same document
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
                // If the anchor actually exists…
                if ($hash.length) {
                    // …don’t jump to the link right away…
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // …and smoothly scroll to it
                    $scrollElement.stop().animate({ 'scrollTop': $hash.offset().top }, speed, function() {
                        location.hash = hash;
                    });
                }
            }
        }).end();
    };

}(document, jQuery));
    </script>
    <script>

        $('html').smoothScroll();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard. This is the much needed solution. I fixed this with the following CSS rule 
`html {
scroll-behaviour: smooth:
}`

Your solution is far better, because with it I can set the speed of scrolling the page.
Thank you once again.

Comment: No worries, if it helped, mark the question as answered.